# How to generate a set of values that follow certain distribution in c++/java?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, math, probability

For example, I have a p.d.f f(x) = 1/25 - x/1250 (from x = 0 to 50);
My question is that how to generate a set of values that satisfy the given p.d.f.
Please give an idea about how to implement in c++ or java.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about directly from a pdf, but you can convert a pdf to a cdf (by integrating) and then use [inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).  This assumes that you have a technique to generate a random number `u` in `[0, 1]` (e.g. `Math.random()` in Java).

Once you have generated such a `u`, find an `x` such that `cdf(x) = u`.  That `x` is the value that you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  One way to thank users for useful answers is to click the "up" button to upvote the answer and click the checkmark to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is similar to `f(x) := 1 - x`. For that case I did the following:

1. integrate the function `f` to yield `F`.
2. normalize the function `F` so that its domain is `[0;1)`, yielding `NF`.
3. invert `NF` to yield `dist`.

Then I used the following code to check the result:

```
package so7691025;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class DistImage {

  private static double dist(double x) {
    return 1.0 - Math.sqrt(1.0 - x);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final Random rnd = new Random(0);

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1000, 1000, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    int[] distrib = new int[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
      distrib[(int) (dist(rnd.nextDouble()) * 1000)]++;
    }

    Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      g.drawLine(i, 1000, i, 1000 - distrib[i]);
    }

    ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("d:/distrib.png"));
  }
}
```

The resulting image looked pretty good to me.

Answer (score 1):

If your values-set is discrete, a valid algorithm is described in the article ["A Linear Algorithm For  Generating  Random Numbers  With  a  Given Distribution"](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~vose/Publications/random.pdf). The algorithm contains a simple pseudo-code, and has O(n) time, where n is the set size.

When the pdf is not discrete, as in your example, see section 5.1 in ["Introduction to Monte Carlo Simulation"](http://www.informs-sim.org/wsc08papers/012.pdf).